# mergAndroid - Can I specify the image optimization when sharing a photo using mergPopActivity?

Tags: android, livecode

I'm using mergPopActivity on Android to share pictures taken with the device camera. When composing an email message with mergPopActivity I get an attachment of 5MB which is the maximum allowed by the Kindle FIre. When sending the same picture with the standard photo album of the device, the file size is of 200/300 KB. Is there in mergPopActivity a way to specify the optimization of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only shares what you give it at the moment although something linked that could be added.